# Modis enumeration definitions

Tags: modis

Modis *MYD03* and *MOD03* files contain *Land/SeaMask* (`uint8` with `valid_range=0,7`) and *WaterPresent* (`uint8` with `valid_range=0,8`). Though the attribute fields define the valid range, they do not define the semantics of the actual values.

- What do the values actually mean?
- Where is a good place to search for these sort of information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [collection 6 MOD03 documentation](http://modaps.nascom.nasa.gov/services/about/products/c6/MOD03.html) the values of the **Land/Sea mask** refer to.

- 0:    Shallow Ocean (Ocean <5k from coast OR <50m deep).
- 1:    Land (not anything else).
- 2:    Ocean Coastlines and Lake Shorelines.
- 3:    Shallow Inland Water (Inland Water < 5km from shore OR < 50m deep).
- 4:    Ephemeral (intermittent) Water.
- 5:    Deep Inland Water (Inland water > 5km from shoreline AND > 50m deep).
- 6:    Moderate or Continental Ocean (Ocean > 5km from coast AND > 50m deep AND < 500m deep).
- 7:    Deep Ocean (Ocean > 500m deep).

**Water Present** is defined as:

```
High resolution water mask  uint8   
The low resolution Land/Water mask is filled in by first
extracting a Land/Water mask value for the center of each 500m
pixel, from a source tabulated with 15 arc second resolution,
and then aggregating those values to 1km resolution, giving the
center two pixels doubled weight. This SDS indicates the total
weight of all high resolution water pixels (Land/Water mask
values 0 or 3-7) that were aggregated into the low resolution
Land/Water mask.
```

NASAs [MODAPS](http://modaps.nascom.nasa.gov/services/about/) website contains information about all **MO**dis **DA**ta **P**roduct**S**.

Comment: Thanks, for the links. After clicking through these pages I still cannot find the definitions for *WaterPresent*.

Comment: See my edit. Both information are from the linked [mod03.geolocation.fs](https://ladsweb.nascom.nasa.gov/filespec/collection6/MOD03.geolocation.fs)

Comment: without going into details of that definition, this basically means: `8=water and nothing else` and `0=land and nothing else` the rest `1,2,...,7=mixture of water and land` ?

Comment: I understand it that way as well. `0` means no-water, `3-7` low to high water coverage, `8` complete water coverage. `1-2` are not possible due to the *doubled weight* of the center two pixels.

Comment: I agree, it reads like this. But I have a file here (`MYD03.A2008001.0040.006.2012201150018.hdf`) containing `1` and `2` ... anyway, thx for your help